# Question about Travel history compilation

Tags: visas, canada

How does this look.

I would be visiting some West African nations for some business transaction over the weekend, but there is apparently an issue here. I would not be having the stamps inside my passport as they just use as means of Identification. And since I would be applying for Canada sometime later, there would be question marks as to why and why not i do not have the stamps there,  Should I have to deal with travel history and there wouldn't be any stamps inside my passport , Can i still in the application have it that i visited those nations -> Its part of travel history also as I see it..

Answer (score 4):

If you are eligible to go to those countries without requiring a visa or a stamp in your passport, there is no compulsion to get such a stamp to prove something to some other countries.

On your Canadian application you can simply mention the fact in your notes.